# Replace an image with an uploaded image (Bootstrap, JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use bootstrap-fileupload.js:

http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#fileupload

But I'm not sure how to use the uploaded image and the remove option. For example: I want to replace an image with the new uploaded one.

The image to be replaced:

```
<img class="background" src="img/background.png" style="position: absolute; top: 190px; left: 138px;"/>
```

From my understanding, something like this should be done with JQuery:

```
$('img.background').attr('src','different/path/to/my/image.jpg');
```

But in my case, it's an uploaded picture - How do I get its path? And how do I use the remove file option? I assume it's something like this?

```
// if the file is removed
$('img.background').attr('src','img/background.png');
```

Comment: You need to know the path where the uploaded file is stored in relation to the web root.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vbrHA/)

**EDIT:** I added a button remove uploaded file as you want,if you don't like **show/hide** effect just delete `slow` , Image is shown only on upload:

```
$('#blah').hide();
$('#remove').hide();  
function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }

    $("#imgInp").change(function(){
        if( $('#imgInp').val()!=""){

            $('#remove').show();
            $('#blah').show('slow');
      }
        else{ $('#remove').hide();$('#blah').hide('slow');}
        readURL(this);
    });


    $('#remove').click(function(){
          $('#imgInp').val('');
          $(this).hide();
          $('#blah').hide('slow');
 $('#blah').attr('src','http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/40/No_pub.svg/150px-No_pub.svg.png');
});
```

---

This s an example made by someone( Not me :) will help you i suppose , see the code below:

```
function readPath(input) {

    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#imgInp").change(function(){
    readPath(this);
});
```

HTML Code:

```
<form id="form1">
    <input type='file' id="imgInp" />
    <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you :) It worked for me, but I wanted a "Remove" option, that's why I wanted to use bootstrap-fileupload.js.

Comment: No need to Bootstrap file upload , i adapted code to your case , check remove button i added http://jsfiddle.net/wLpDu/

Comment: Thank you very much again. It also works, but the remove button doesn't always show up - Only after I choose again a different file.